# WDC 2 in tableau 9

Tags: tableau-api

wdc 2 is available on [github](https://github.com/tableau/webdataconnector/tree/dev) and still in development and compatible with tableau 10 beta. I tried using it on tableau 9 via web data connector and it says

> The version of Tableau that you are using cannot use the web data connector that you are trying to access. The connector requires at least version '2.0.0' of the web data connector API.

Is there any way of using wdc 2 on tableau 9 ?

Comment: Hey @Eka, PM for WDC here.  Unfortunately that isn't something that will be possible.  Version 2.0 is a breaking change so you won't be able to utilize 2.0 connectors in Tableau 9.  We will be backwards compatible though (any connector built with WDC 1.0 will work in any version of Tableau after 9.1 - when WDC was introduced.)

Comment: so is it means that wdc 2 available through simulator only?

Comment: WDC 2.0 is currently in beta and we've released in on GitHub first as a preview for developers so that we could gather some feedback.  So yes, it is currently just available in the simulator.  2.0 will be in the Tableau Desktop Beta soon, if you'd like to sign up for that you can do so here: http://www.tableau.com/tableau-10-beta-program